# проверка правильно ли пользователь ввел имя, если нет вернуть обратно, написал функцию examination

Tags: python, json, функции

Данная функция должна проверить то ли имя ввел пользователь, не понимаю куда передать значение если имя верное

```py
import json

def ger_stored_username():
    filename = 'username.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            username = json.load(f_obj)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username
def get_new_username():
    username = input("What's your name? ")
    filename = 'username.json'
    with open(filename,'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(username,f_obj)
    return username

def examination():
    print('Are you sure& ' + get_new_username(), ' yes\no')
    sogl = input()
    if sogl == 'yes':
        return greet_user()
    if sogl == 'no':
        return get_new_username()
    
    

def greet_user():
    username = examination()
    if username:
        print('Welcome back ' + username)
    else:
        username = examination()
    
greet_user()
```